# How to use SendKeys(webdriver) command in Rich Text editor that is located in iframe

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing the following problem.I can not type text in iframe in which there is a text editor:Here is the html:

```
<iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;  height: 100%;" aria-describedby="cke_39" title="Текстов редактор за форматиран текст,description1" src="" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="bg" dir="ltr">
<head>
<body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
<p>
<br>
</p>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Here is what I have done so far,but the test passed successfully and no text is writen in the text editor.May be the solution is with Javascript executor but I'm not familiar with it.

```
WaitTool.waitForElementPresent(Browser.instance, By.tagName("iframe"), 10);
WebElement iframe = Browser.instance.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
Browser.instance.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement description=Browser.instance.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@class='cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr']"));
description.click();
description.sendKeys("someText");
Browser.instance.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. Here's an article you might want to have a look.

[Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/)

- Send keys directly

This approach is the one you have tried and didn't work. Please try make sure your locators to `<iframe>` and `<body>` are correct. Otherwise I'd suggest using `JavaScriptExecutor` for more stable solutions.

- Set innerHTML

```java
WaitTool.waitForElementPresent(Browser.instance, By.className("cke_wysiwyg_frame"), 10);
WebElement iframe = Browser.instance.findElement(By.className("cke_wysiwyg_frame"));
Browser.instance.switchTo().frame(iframe);

WebElement description = Browser.instance.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
(JavascriptExecutor)Browser.instance.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Set text using innerHTML</h1>'", description);
```

- Use CKEditor's native API

```java
// no need to switch iframe
(JavascriptExecutor)Browser.instance.executeScript("CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.setData('<h1>Native API text</h1> Editor')");
```

Comment: Thank you for the explicit answer ,user1177636.It works!

Comment: how to get this JS code work for `redactor-editor`. Its API is  [here](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/)??