# Unable to type in Rich Text Editor

Tags: php, html, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I want to make Selenium to type a text in a Rich Text iframe, but I can't make it to work. This is the HTML of the iframe: `<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 1635px; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, question" aria-describedby="cke_94" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`
My steps are:

```
$this->selectFrame("xpath=//*[contains (@class, 'cke_wysiwyg_frame')]");
$this->type("xpath=//*[contains (@class, 'cke_wysiwyg_frame')]", $this->contextQuestion);
```

The thing is, for some reason it  doesn't find the element. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What if you omit the `selectFrame` call?

Comment: @alecxe Same thing... doesn't fine the element

Comment: Had similar trouble a few months ago. And it was with the CK Editor as well. I found that latching to the iFrame itself was not enough. You have to really drill down.  Also I didn't use `type` but set the value instead. Hope it helps.

Comment: Remembered a bit more now. The item you need to reference with Selenium is inside the HTML of the iFrame. The class name is significant so you are on the right track, however I'd suggest using Firebug or other to really get down deep into the many nested HTML structures you will find in that CKEditor code embed.

Comment: @AdamT I think you mean the body of the iframe, but it can't find the element, meaning it doesn't even show up during the test.

Comment: @Denki sorry was away for a bit. I looked for my old code but could not find. There are a few forums with SauceLabs (their export forum specifically) but I can no longer access it because my account was closed. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: @Denki I found 3 links that may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839183/how-to-use-sendkeyswebdriver-command-in-rich-text-editor-that-is-located-in-if
 http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/
 https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7087

Comment: I may have used a pattern that executes javascript code by which to latch on to the CKEditor, again I cannot get to my old code to verify (sorry).