# Not able to type in Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, selenium, iframe

I want Selenium to type a text in a Rich Text iframe, but I can't get it to work. This is the iframe: `<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 1635px; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, question" aria-describedby="cke_94" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`
My steps are:

```
$this->selectFrame("xpath=//*[contains (@class, 'cke_wysiwyg_frame')]");
$this->type("xpath=//*[contains (@class, 'cke_wysiwyg_frame')]", $this->contextQuestion);
```

It says that, for some reason, it doesn't find the element, maybe it doesn't load the JS ?. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you may have to tell Selenium to execute Javascript code. Once you have the class name, you might be able to use ? jQuery ? and populate the CKEditor that way. I had solved this a few months ago, and no longer have access to my code (it was code-for-hire).

Perhaps these 3 links could provide some help.

[How to use SendKeys(webdriver) command in Rich Text editor that is located in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839183/how-to-use-sendkeyswebdriver-command-in-rich-text-editor-that-is-located-in-if)
http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7087

Comment: @milen were you able to sort this out? I found the code that I was looking for